# Changing font color when comparing fields in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reportbuilder3.0, srs

Report Builder 3.0
I have 2 columns - one is est hours - one is act hours
I want to change the hours in the act to "red" when it is higher than the estimate hours

I have tried the following

IIF(Fields!AcutalHours.Value > Fields!Estimate_Hours.Value "Red"

and I have tried the following

=Switch(Fields!Estimate_Hours.Value < Fields!AcutalHours.Value, "Black"), 
=Switch(Fields!AcutalHours.Value > Fields!Estimate_Hours.Value, " Red ")

I am using the font expression

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields definitely Numeric? Try converting them to Int to ensure it's comparing them as numbers.:

=Iif(CInt(Fields!ActualHours.Value) > CInt(Fields!Estimate_Hours.Value), "Red", "Black")

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new calculated field to your Dataset in ReportBuilder with a formula like this:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!Original.Value,Fields!Updated.Value)>0, "White","Red")
```

Once that is done, Select the properties of the field that needs to be formatted, select fill, formula and set the expression for the BackgroundColor to

```
=Fields!MyCustomDiffField.Value
```

I use this method of formatting in Report Builder 3.0